# EF error on updating entity/model :The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a table named `RFM_NOTF_Notifications` which has a reference to another table `RFM_NOTD_NotificationsDetail`. I'm using EF to communicate with database and `NotificationsDetail` entity has a list of `Notifications`.

When I tried to update a list of `Notifications` entity, I'm getting this error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_RFM_NOTF_Notifications_RFM_NOTD_NotificationsDetail". The conflict occurred in database "RegulatoryFileManagementScrumQA", table "dbo.RFM_NOTD_NotificationsDetail", column 'RFM_NOTD_P_NotificationDetailID'

And this is the add/update method inside repository:

```
private void CreateNotifications(GeneralBO file, RFM_NOTD_NotificationsDetail notfFile)
{
        foreach (NotificationsBO notf in file.Notifications)
        {
            RFM_NOTF_Notifications nt = new RFM_NOTF_Notifications
            {
                RFM_NOTF_B_Description = notf.Description
            };

            if(notf.Id > 0)   // Save
            {
                nt.RFM_NOTF_P_NotificationID = notf.Id;
                nt.RFM_NOTD_F_NotificationDetailID = file.Id;

                nt.RFM_NOTF_M_ModifiedById = file.CreatedById;
                nt.RFM_NOTF_M_ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                new GenericRepository<RFM_NOTF_Notifications>(_dbContext).update(nt);                    
            }
            else
            {
                nt.RFM_NOTF_M_CreatedById = file.CreatedById;
                nt.RFM_NOTF_M_CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                notfFile.RFM_NOTF_Notifications.Add(nt);
            }
        }
}
```

`GeneralBO` is the model/object which hold data from UI.

And these are the business objects/model

```
public class NotificationsBO 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationDetailsBO : ApplicationBO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    .......
    .......
    public List<NotificationsBO> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

And my tables are:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `nt.RFM_NOTD_F_NotificationDetailID = file.Id;` I think there is no record in `NotificationDetails` table with `file.Id`.

Something caught my attention, there is a parameter which are passed the method with named `RFM_NOTD_NotificationsDetail notfFile`. I don't know that data where it is being came from and it's purpose but would you try like this;

```
nt.RFM_NOTD_F_NotificationDetailID = notfFile.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first explain what does that error means.

> The Update statement conflicted with the Foreign Key

It simply means that the primary key of table `Notifications` is a foreign key in the `Notification Detail` table so you can't change it as it is a conflict clearly.

Here are a few solutions that you can try. (not recommended)

- Remove the Notification Details first and then Remove Notifications

or the better solution is to use

- Fluent API to implement cascade delete which will delete the values from **Notifications Detail** table as soon as you will delete the data from **Notifications Table**

and you can achieve the same in the database using

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT [New_FK_Constraint]
FOREIGN KEY (ColumnName) REFERENCES SecondTable(ColumnName)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
```

AND in case of an update.

You need to use the **EntityStateModified** property of Entity Framework to better implement the update feature